# What is Illegal Self Reference in Java?

Tags: java, variable-declaration

When I try to compile the following class

```
class C1 {
  Integer v1 = v1;
}
```

I get `Illegal Self Reference` error. Now consider another class as below.

```
class C2 {
  Integer v1;
  {
    v1 = v1;
  }
}
```

And it compiles. What's the difference between both the classes and why does one compile and one does not.

UPDATE:

If `v1` has not become available in the class `C1`, then why does the following class work too?

```
class C3 {
  Integer v1 = v1 = 1;
}
```

In the above `C3` class `v1` is available for the Expression `v1 = 1` to be evaluated but it doesn't work the same in `C1`. Can you explain?

Comment: Difference is declaration and declaration + definition.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first doesnt compile because you assign v1 itself to v1 and since v1 isnt make yet it doesnt work. On the second one you create v1  and then you assigne v1 to v1 but since v1 already exist , it works

Comment: In the case of `Integer v1 = v1`, the variable `v1` does not yet exist, so the RHS is not defined.  In your second case, `v1` is already defined.

Comment: But, `Integer v1 = v1 = 1;` works. If such syntax works then should it mean that `v1` is ready as soon as LHS? @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: @AmrishKumar That one works because assignment is right-associative, so `v1` has a value when it is self-assigned.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It exists in terms of declarations, but it doesn't yet have a value.

Comment: Does this does mean some initial values are assigned to the fields say `null` before executing the block in `C2` which are not done so in `Integer v1 = v1;` in `C1`? @user207421

Comment: @AmrishKumar In `C1` there is a member declaration without initialization, which gets a default value of `null`, so the assignment in the static block is legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v1` starts to exists after you define it, so when you try to save the value to itself it doesn't exist yet:

```
class C1 {
    Integer v1 = v1;
//declaring-^     ^-doesn't exist yet
}
```

This is an equivalent code:

```
public class SomeClass {
    Integer v1;
```

//declaring....^

```
    public SomeClass() {
        this.v1 = v1;
//           ^-----^
//              |
//          both exist
    }
}
```

In your example, the instance block code is executed after the variable is declared, just like the constructor:

```
class C2 {
  Integer v1;
  {
    v1 = v1;  // instance block executed after variable declaration
  }
}
```

the last part of the updated question is very well explained here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205079/what-is-the-difference-advantage-of-doing-double-assignment

and answer in the comment of the user @user207421 (about right association)

Comment: I don't think this has to anything with the availability of `v1` as said so in your answer and `C3` is my evidence. @Damián Rafael Lattenero

Comment: @AmrishKumar your new example is different again. `Integer v1` declares the variable (compile time), and at runtime `v1 = 1` is executed as an expression whose value is assigned to `v1`. So it’s really `Integer v1 = (v1  = 1);`. You give `v1` a value, and so it is available for referencing.

Comment: @AmrishKumar what you shouldn’t do, however, is move the goalposts after your question was answered. Your C3 part is essentially a new question.

Comment: I had included the `C3` part just as an evidence that `v1` is available as a variable for the RHS in `C1`. Earlier I had to explain this to each and every comment on the question. I don't see how this changes the original motive of the question. I have referenced `C1` at the end of the update and still ask only to explain my earlier doubt. @MartijnPieters